# How do I extract multiple keywords on a certain descriptions

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nlp

Here's my dataset

```
No   Description
1    Paying Google ads
2    Purchasing Facebook Ads
3    Purchasing Ads
4    AirBnB repayment
```

I have `txt` files called `entity.txt`

```
0, Google
1, Facebook
2, Ads
```

What I need is detect all the keyword on `entity.txt` in my dataframe either only single or multiple keywords and if no one keyword detected we call it `Other`, so My Output expectation is:

```
No   Description                 Keyword
1    Paying Google ads           Google
2    Purchasing Facebook Ads     Facebook Ads
3    Purchasing LinkedIn Ads     LinkedIn Ads
4    AirBnB repayment            Other
```

Here's what I did

```
with open('entity.txt') as f: 
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content ]
df['keyword'] = df['description'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([i for i in content if i in x]))
df['keyword'] = df['keyword'].replace('', 'Other')
```

But, the result is

```
No   Description                 Keyword
1    Paying Google ads           Other
2    Purchasing Facebook Ads     Other
3    Purchasing LinkedIn Ads     Other
4    AirBnB repayment            Other
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) for extract all values from `df1` to lists, then convert empty lists to `Other` and all filled ones join by space with [`str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'entity':['Google','Facebook','Ads']})

s = df['Description'].str.findall(r'({})'.format('|'.join(df1['entity'])))
df['Keyword'] = np.where(s.astype(bool), s.str.join(' '), 'Other')
print (df)

   No              Description       Keyword
0   1        Paying Google ads        Google
1   2  Purchasing Facebook Ads  Facebook Ads
2   3  Purchasing LinkedIn Ads           Ads
3   4         AirBnB repayment         Other
```

Your solution:

```
s = df['Description'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in set(df1['entity']) if i in x])
df['Keyword'] = np.where(s.astype(bool), s.str.join(' '), 'Other')
print (df)
   No              Description       Keyword
0   1        Paying Google ads        Google
1   2  Purchasing Facebook Ads  Facebook Ads
2   3  Purchasing LinkedIn Ads           Ads
3   4         AirBnB repayment         Other
```

Alternative:

```
out = []
for x in df['Description']:
    L = [i for i in set(df1['entity']) if i in x]
    if bool(L):
        out.append(' '.join(L))
    else:
        out.append('Other')
df['Keyword'] = out
print (df)
   No              Description       Keyword
0   1        Paying Google ads        Google
1   2  Purchasing Facebook Ads  Facebook Ads
2   3  Purchasing LinkedIn Ads           Ads
3   4         AirBnB repayment         Other
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `findall`

```
df.Description.str.findall(('|'.join(s.tolist()))).str[0]
0      Google
1    Facebook
2         Ads
3         NaN
Name: Description, dtype: object
df['Keyword']=df.Description.str.findall(('|'.join(s.tolist()))).str[0]
```

---

Data input

```
s
0      Google
1    Facebook
2         Ads
Name: s, dtype: object
```

Comment: what is `s`, can you elaborate?

Comment: @NabihBawazir your text file entity.txt

Comment: Sorry, it is not working if we have multiple keyword in one description

Answer (score 2):

Using `str.extract()`

```
df['Keyword']=df.Description.str.extract(r'({})'.format('|'.join(df1[1],)))
print(df)

  No              Description    Keyword
0   1        Paying Google ads     Google
1   2  Purchasing Facebook Ads   Facebook
2   3  Purchasing LinkedIn Ads        Ads
3   4         AirBnB repayment        NaN
```

Comment: How about multiple keyword in one description ?

Comment: @NabihBawazir didnt get it sorry, you mean you want to map multiple keywords for each row? if so how? can you add a sample please?